# find and replace value in SED linux

Tags: linux, shell, sed

i have a file called form.php:

```
<?php
sleep(10);
?>
```

The purpose is to execute a shell script like this with sed:

```
$sh example.sh form.php 50
```

For obtain:

```
<?php
sleep(50);
?>
```

I tried this

```
$cat example.sh
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
sed -i "s/^\( *sleep\)\([^>]*\)</\1$2</" "$1"
```

but dont work...

Comment: "dont work..." tells us very little. What error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed "s/sleep([^)]*)/sleep($2)/" "$file"
```

or this one:

```
sed "s/\(sleep\)([^)]*)/\1($2)/" "$file"
```

`sed` use BRE by default and `( or )` take as literal not as special regex meta character.